# unable to print single record instead of getting multiple records in crystal report and Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, crystal-reports

i want to print 1 single record or single registered student details in the crystal report. but here im getting multiple records. how to write code to get single record/ latest record of the table

```
    StudentDBEntities db = new StudentDBEntities();
    CrystalReportProduct cr = new CrystalReportProduct();
    cr.SetDataSource(db.Students.Select(p => new
    {
        sno = p.sno,
        name =p.sname,
        phone=p.phone,
        email = p.email,
        course = p.course,
        date=p.date,
        paymentmode=p.paymentMode,
        amount=p.amount

    }));

    this.CrystalReportViewerProduct.ReportSource = cr;
    this.CrystalReportViewerProduct.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OrderByDescending(p => p.sno)` to sort by sno, and then `Take(1)`:

```
cr.SetDataSource(db.Students.Select(p => new
{
    sno = p.sno,
    name =p.sname,
    phone=p.phone,
    email = p.email,
    course = p.course,
    date=p.date,
    paymentmode=p.paymentMode,
    amount=p.amount

}).OrderByDescending(p => p.sno).Take(1));
```

Comment: got error
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '<>f__AnonymousType0`8

Comment: Sorry, that's because the DB doesn't support taking the last object. You can take the `First()`, or if you want the last, you can use `OrderByDescending` to order your objects, and then take the `First()`.

Comment: im new linq can u tell me how to write order by descending in above query @tomer

Comment: again got error -'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException' occurred in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: cant we use simple dataset and assign to crystal reports.

Comment: Try replacing `FirstOrDefault()` with `Limit(1)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114460/discussion-between-stack2-and-tomer).